# Can't center <article> with divs in

Tags: html, css

Hello there I am trying to center an article that contains some divs but for some reason nothing is working I tried auto margins also giving the article a width but nothing seems to work anyone know how to solve this? I am probably doing something wrong in terms of using an article with divs?

```css
html body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    animation-name: background;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

article {
    border: solid 1px red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}

.imgborder {
    border: solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
    background: ghostwhite;
    margin: 2% auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.imgborder img {
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
}
.imgborder p {

}
/*Animations*/
@keyframes background {
    from {
        background-image: url("../images/background.jpg")
    }
    to {
        background-image: url("../images/background2.jpg")
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
    <title>Fotografie</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav id="navi_bar">
    <ul>
        <li id="active">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/info.html">Info</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/apparatuur.html">Apparatuur</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/apparatuur.html">Categorieën</a>
            <!--<ul>
                <li><a href="html/.">Portretten</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/.">Landschappen</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/.">Dieren</a></li>
            </ul>-->
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<article>
    <div class="imgborder">
        <img src="images/portretten/img1thumb.jpg" alt="meisje met sproeten zwart wit">
        <p>portretten</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgborder">
        <img src="images/landschap/img1thumb.jpg" alt="landschap boom zwart wit">
        <p>landschappen</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgborder">
        <img src="images/dieren/img1thumb.jpg" alt="kat liggend zwart wit">
        <p>dieren</p>

    </div>
</article>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the article tag inside a main tag and give it 100% width and center align

```css
html body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    animation-name: background;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

main{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    
}

article {
    border: solid 1px red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
}

.imgborder {
    border: solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
    background: ghostwhite;
    margin: 2% auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.imgborder img {
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
}
.imgborder p {

}
/*Animations*/
@keyframes background {
    from {
        background-image: url("../images/background.jpg")
    }
    to {
        background-image: url("../images/background2.jpg")
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
    <title>Fotografie</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav id="navi_bar">
    <ul>
        <li id="active">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/info.html">Info</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/apparatuur.html">Apparatuur</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/apparatuur.html">Categorieën</a>
            <!--<ul>
                <li><a href="html/.">Portretten</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/.">Landschappen</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/.">Dieren</a></li>
            </ul>-->
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<main>

<article>
    <div class="imgborder">
        <img src="images/portretten/img1thumb.jpg" alt="meisje met sproeten zwart wit">
        <p>portretten</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgborder">
        <img src="images/landschap/img1thumb.jpg" alt="landschap boom zwart wit">
        <p>landschappen</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgborder">
        <img src="images/dieren/img1thumb.jpg" alt="kat liggend zwart wit">
        <p>dieren</p>

    </div>
</article>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using `display:inline-block`.Replace that with `display:block` in article.I have given `width:50%;` to make it look better.

```css
html body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  animation-name: background;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

article {
  width: 50%;
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.imgborder {
  border: solid 1px;
  text-align: center;
  background: ghostwhite;
  margin: 2% auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.imgborder img {
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
}

.imgborder p {}


/*Animations*/

@keyframes background {
  from {
    background-image: url("../images/background.jpg")
  }
  to {
    background-image: url("../images/background2.jpg")
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
  <title>Fotografie</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="navi_bar">
    <ul>
      <li id="active">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>

      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="html/info.html">Info</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="html/apparatuur.html">Apparatuur</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="html/contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="html/apparatuur.html">Categorieën</a>
        <!--<ul>
                <li><a href="html/.">Portretten</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/.">Landschappen</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/.">Dieren</a></li>
            </ul>-->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <article>
    <div class="imgborder">
      <img src="images/portretten/img1thumb.jpg" alt="meisje met sproeten zwart wit">
      <p>portretten</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgborder">
      <img src="images/landschap/img1thumb.jpg" alt="landschap boom zwart wit">
      <p>landschappen</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgborder">
      <img src="images/dieren/img1thumb.jpg" alt="kat liggend zwart wit">
      <p>dieren</p>

    </div>
  </article>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    animation-name: background;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

article {
    border: solid 1px red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.imgborder {
    border: solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
    background: ghostwhite;
    margin: 2% auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.imgborder img {
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
}
.imgborder p {

}
/*Animations*/
@keyframes background {
    from {
        background-image: url("../images/background.jpg")
    }
    to {
        background-image: url("../images/background2.jpg")
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
    <title>Fotografie</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav id="navi_bar">
    <ul>
        <li id="active">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/info.html">Info</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/apparatuur.html">Apparatuur</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/apparatuur.html">Categorieën</a>
            <!--<ul>
                <li><a href="html/.">Portretten</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/.">Landschappen</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/.">Dieren</a></li>
            </ul>-->
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div align="center">
  


<article>
    <div class="imgborder">
        <img src="images/portretten/img1thumb.jpg" alt="meisje met sproeten zwart wit">
        <p>portretten</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgborder">
        <img src="images/landschap/img1thumb.jpg" alt="landschap boom zwart wit">
        <p>landschappen</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgborder">
        <img src="images/dieren/img1thumb.jpg" alt="kat liggend zwart wit">
        <p>dieren</p>

    </div>
</article>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave the article a `width:100%;` and gave the div within the article a `max-wdith`.

```css
html body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    animation-name: background;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

article {
    width:100%;
    border: solid 1px red;
    display: inline-block;
}
article div {
  max-width:200px;
}

.imgborder {
    border: solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
    background: ghostwhite;
    margin: 2% auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.imgborder img {
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
}
.imgborder p {

}
/*Animations*/
@keyframes background {
    from {
        background-image: url("../images/background.jpg")
    }
    to {
        background-image: url("../images/background2.jpg")
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
    <title>Fotografie</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav id="navi_bar">
    <ul>
        <li id="active">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/info.html">Info</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/apparatuur.html">Apparatuur</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="html/apparatuur.html">Categorieën</a>
            <!--<ul>
                <li><a href="html/.">Portretten</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/.">Landschappen</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/.">Dieren</a></li>
            </ul>-->
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<article>
    <div class="imgborder">
        <img src="images/portretten/img1thumb.jpg" alt="meisje met sproeten zwart wit">
        <p>portretten</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgborder">
        <img src="images/landschap/img1thumb.jpg" alt="landschap boom zwart wit">
        <p>landschappen</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgborder">
        <img src="images/dieren/img1thumb.jpg" alt="kat liggend zwart wit">
        <p>dieren</p>

    </div>
</article>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
article {
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.imgborder {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
    background: ghostwhite;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```